# eventListener and enclosed elements

Tags: javascript, html

There is a piece of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Events Examples</title>
    <style>
        ul {
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            margin: 10px;
            background-color: #ccc;
            float: left;
        }

        .highlight {
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="list">
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
</ul>
<script>
    const ul = document.querySelector('#list');
    ul.addEventListener('mouseover', highlight);
    ul.addEventListener('mouseout', highlight);

    function highlight(event) {
        console.log(event.target);
        event.target.classList.toggle('highlight');
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When started, it looks like this:

[image]

What I expect from listeners. When I move the mouse over the grey zone of 'ul', then highlight() function should work. Well, it works fine. What I don't understand: when I move the mouse over 'li' elements, then highlight() works again for unknown reason. How can it be fixed?
I'm new to JS and I have not found the answer to the problem described.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events always bubble up, but if you want to select the element that you actually added the listener to, use `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target`.

```
function highlight(event) {
    console.log(event.currentTarget);
    event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('highlight');
}
```

Information on event bubbling: [What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

If you want to be sure that the event only gets called on the element that you registered it on, you can check if `target` matches [`currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget).

Comment: Wouldn't `highlight` still be called twice though? Once when entering or exiting the `ul` and again when entering or exiting `li`..?

Comment: 'if (event.target !== event.currentTarget) return;' — this line should be deleted

Comment: Why? That was added to fix the problem @Terminus mentioned above.

Comment: Without this line I have the behavior I wanted: the rectangle is red while the cursor is inside it. But with this line when I move the mouse over 'li', the rectangle gets grey again. I need it to remain red until I move the mouse beyond its outer ages.

Comment: OP has a point. If the `if ...` is removed, then the whole `ul` is highlighted, even while mousing over the `li`s. With the `if`, mousing into the `ul` highlights it but, mousing into the `li`s removes the highlight. [see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L6a4uemk/)(compare and contrast with the `if` commented).

Comment: That's because when mousing over the `li`, the `mouseout` takes place on the `ul`, even though you're still within its boundaries. To do it with a bubbling event and without having redundant class setting, you'd need to involve `event.relatedTarget`, but that gets a little tricky.

Comment: @rockstar Good point. In other words, when you move the mouse over a list item, a `mouseout` gets called on the `ul`,  then a `mouseover` gets called on the `li`. That seems like it could possibly cause a flash/race condition. In that case, your answer is probably better.

Comment: Ultimately, the best solution would be to do this with CSS instead of JS by using `ul:hover { ... }`

Comment: Completely agree, if that is the entire point of the OP, that's what I would recommend.

Answer (score 2):

If you're saying you only want to highlight the entire region, then use `"mouseenter"` and `"mouseleave"` instead, and `this` to reference the element.

Then there's no event bubbling issue to have to deal with.

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('#list');
ul.addEventListener('mouseenter', highlight);
ul.addEventListener('mouseleave', highlight);

function highlight(event) {
  this.classList.toggle('highlight');
}
```

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  float: left;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul id="list">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mouseover one element contained within another, the "inner" element (in your case the `<li>` will fire a mouseover event, and this will "bubble" up to the element where you attached the listener. The `target` property on the event will be the inner element that triggered the event, not the one where you attached the listener.

Rather than target, use `currentTarget`, which indicates the element that you attached the listener to.

**update** As @Terminus points out, this could lead to multiple handlings of the event, since mousing over both the li and the ul will trigger mouseover events that get handled by the listener. The solution would then be to only run the code if the target *is* the currentTarget

```
if(event.target === event.currentTarget)
     event.currentTarget.classList.toggle('highlight');
```

Comment: Wouldn't `highlight` still be called twice though? Once when entering or exiting the `ul` and again when entering or exiting `li`..?